# Angular 12 with ldapjs polyfill errors

Tags: angular, ldap, polyfills

I'm currently trying to build an Angular 12 application that supports login with LDAP credentials and is able to retrieve a custom ldap field. For LDAP access, tried to use ldapts (https://github.com/ldapts/ldapts).

After installing ldapts (npm install ldapts) I get the following messages:

```
If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "assert": require.resolve("assert/") }'
    - install 'assert'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "assert": false }
```

This message is coming up for util,assert,tls,stream,net.

I installed util,assert,tls,stream-browserify,net and added them to tsconfig.json

```
"compilerOptions":{
"paths": {
  "util":["node_modules/util"],
  "assert":["node_modules/assert"],
  "tls":["node_modules/tls"],
  "stream":["node_modules/stream-browserify"],
  "net":["node_modules/net"],
}
}
```

Now the code compiles without warning, but the web application is broken:
Only output of the browser console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined     util.js:109 
   at Object.4655 (util.js:109)
   at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
   at Object.5025 (assertion_error.js:35)
   at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
   at Object.5652 (assert.js:36)
   at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
   at Object.4590 (reader.js:3)
   at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
   at Object.9438 (index.js:6)
   at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
```

How to use Angular 12 in conjunction with ldapts?
How to fix webpack polyfill errors the correct way?

Or is there an alternative ldap package that works with Angular 12 out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO using the ldapjs directly in an angular app is not possible, since the ldapjs library is a pure node.js library and the LDAP protocol is not accessable from the browser. You must do the LDAP stuff in the backend